# How do I automatically delete pictures when I delete rows?

Tags: excel, image, rows

I would like to request help. I have on my hands a lot of excel sheets that has a picture in every row. When I copy and paste rows, the pictures are copied into the pasted rows as well. However, when I want to delete rows, the picture does not get deleted. Instead, it "hides" behind the picture of the next row.

Also, when I sort/filter the list, the pictures does not seem to follow. The picture stays in the same place, but all the other values are sorted/filtered. My job is to delete and randomise some of the entries, so you can imagine my woes with all the stubborn pictures that just refuse to belong in its own row. Currently, I am able to filter, highlight the cells I want to delete, unfilter (so that the pictures match the rows), delete the pictures and then delete the rows manually. As for randomisation, I am stuck as using the "RAND()" function in excel requires sorting of rows, which will mess up the pictures.

I would greatly appreciate if somebody could provide a solution on how to work around this problem. This forum thread http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=85597 also describes what I am experiencing. However, when I tried the VBA code, it says "run-time error 13" and I don't know what that means. Trying that code was my very first try with VBAs and macros, but I am pretty confident that I followed instructions on how to add and run them properly. It debugged at the sentence `For Each sh In Shapes`.

Some more details:
My picture properties are set as "Move and size with cells". 
There is also only one picture per row, not counting the heading. If you guys require me to send the excel file, I am unable to do so as it contains private information. However, I am able to change the data. Hope that will work!

Answer (score 0):

Pictures float above cells:

[image]

The **upper left**-hand corner is in cell **B2**............we can use this to decide which pictures to delete **before** deleting the row.  So if we want to delete row #2 and its associated pictures:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim shp As Shape, rng As Range
    Dim WhichRow As Long

    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        Set rng = shp.TopLeftCell
        WhichRow = rng.Row
        If WhichRow = 2 Then shp.Delete
    Next shp
End Sub
```

*Then delete row#2*